# How to structure a very large R package

Tags: r, devtools

I'm debating on how to structure my R package. It is difficult to create a minimal working example, but I'll try to explain via an analogy. I need to read in, analyse and visualise data for 4 different types of projects. The reading and analysing will be mostly different for the 4 types of projects, but the visualising will have many similarities (plot style, plot type, LaTeX output using the same LaTeX .sty file, etc).

Now I'm thinking of how to include this so it will remain structurally nice. I have seen large packages created as a group of multiple packages in Python (example is [Qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit), made up of Terra, Aer, Ignis and Aqua), but could not find anything online about R. The reason I want this is because I want everything grouped together nicely for these 4 types of projects.

So say I have these 4 types of projects all needing a package `pkg-type-i` (`i` from `1` to `4`) with in their `R/` folders the files `fnct1.R`, `fnct2.R` etc, should (and *can*) I make:

- `big-pkg` consisting of

  1. `pkg-type-1/`
  2. `pkg-type-2/`
  3. `pkg-type-3/`
  4. `pkg-type-4/`
  5. `pkg-visualisation/`

Or should I structure it as follows, with my `R/` directory in `big-pkg` as follows:

- `R/`

  - `type1.fnct1.R`
  - `type1.fnct2.R`
  - `...`
  - `type2.fnct1.R`
  - `...`
  - `visualisation.R`

The final option is how structuring a package is being taught in [r-pkgs.org](https://r-pkgs.org/index.html) but the toy package there is way smaller. I want to have this structurally neat so one can find everything quickly. I do not know where to look for how to structure a package this big and want to prevent having an `R/` folder that large. So what is the best solution here?

Comment: It is hard to answer because there will be a lot of opinions on this. But if all of the functions achieve a similar goal, that is fit under a central idea, then make one package. If you have a situation where you would call each individual package and not need the others, make sperate packages.

Comment: But is it then advised to create only separate packages, or is it possible to create a package made up of multiple packages? I have not found anything regarding that last design choice and do not know if it is a wise one either.

Comment: the answer below is probably what you are looking for, however, even when grouping packages they have to be their own entity and then you create a meta-package to call all of them

Answer (score 1):

The idea of grouping several packages into a meta-package is not uncommon. For instance, there is the [tidyverse](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse) package, or the [mlr3verse](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3verse), or the [healthyverse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/healthyverse/index.html).

There is even a package [pkgverse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pkgverse/index.html) which aims to help creating meta-packages.

If you are working with S4 classes, implementing generics over different packages can be more difficult than with R6.

Comment: Thank you for this. Will look into that.